# Class-based view delegate to another view

Tags: django

Is it possible to have a class based view delegate to a particular class-based view? Specifically what I'd like to do is have / point to a view called 'home' and the home view with delegate to View A if the user is logged in, or View B if no user is logged in. Alternatively I could do a redirect to a different URL. I'm not sure what would be the best practice here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call another view from within a view in the same manner used in urls

```
class HomeView( TemplateView ):
  template_name="index.html"

  def dispatch( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
      view=UserHomeView.as_view()
      return view( request, *args, **kwargs )
    return super( HomeView, self ).dispatch( request, *args, **kwargs )


class UserHomeView( TemplateView ):
  template_name="user.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just redirect to a different url and that url is also served by a class based view.

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^welcome/$', WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome')
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('welcome'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))

class WelcomeView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #do something

class LoginView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #show login page
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to ensure that user must be authenticated is use Mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    u"""Ensures that user must be authenticated in order to access view."""

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #do something
```

Comment: Sure, but this could be done just for the view that serves logged in users. Your answer doesn't address how to use 1 view for logged in users and 1 view for non-logged in users, for a given URL.